# Short story in English book during high school(70s) about alien who visits boy in his home. Similar to Mork, but more serious

Tags: story-identification, aliens

During ninth grade English, a short story in my textbook was about an alien who visits a boy in his home.  At first, the alien seems friendly and funny, but he then reveals a more menacing side.  Somehow the boy is able to make the alien leave.  Pretty certain that I read an article way back when that stated the premise of Mork's visit to Richie Cunningham on *Happy Days* was very similar to this short story, but that Mork was made to be funny instead of menacing.